# Update through React.render gives strange results

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a web app using React, and due to the way a UI framework works I need to use multiple React components mounted to divs in thew Html. To update these divs I call React.render again to update the different components.

This works really well on my own machine, but as soon as I deploy a minimized version on the location http://svdoever.github.io/trainercoach I get strange behaviour.

Reproduction steps:

1. Navigate to http://svdoever.github.io/trainercoach
2. Click the hamburger menu
3. Select an item in the menu (opens up an exercises set)
4. At the bottom press the ">" next button
5. A reload of the app seems to occur

The initial rendered HTML is:

[image: Initial rendering]

After selecting the ">" next button which calls `renderExercise()`, there seems to be a kind of "reload" of the whole app within a new generated div:

[image: Strange rendering after call to React.render to update component]

The new introduced div is:

`<div data-title="http://svdoever.github.io/trainercoach/" id="1452577160" class="panel active" data-crc="1452577160" style="z-index: 10;">`

And this div contains all kind of stuff from the whole rendered page, like tag that are defined in the  tag.

React sees this as a mismatching server-side rendering and comes with the error:

`Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) <ul class="list ins
 (server) <ul class="list ins`

In my opinion there should only be an update, no introduction of a new div.

The relevant code:

```
    function renderIndex(source) {
        var context = { rootUri: source.substring(0, source.lastIndexOf( "/" )) };
        $.get(source + "?v=" + Math.random().toString(), function (indexMarkdown) {
            $.afui.hideMask();
            var indexManager =  new IndexManager(source, indexMarkdown, this.rootUri);
            React.render(<Index key="index" indexManager={indexManager}/>, document.getElementById('mountIndexLeftMenu'));
        }.bind(context));
    }

    function renderExercises(source) {
        var context = { rootUri: source.substring(0, source.lastIndexOf( "/" )) };
        $.get(source + "?v=" + Math.random().toString(), function (exercisesMarkdown) {
            $.afui.hideMask();
            var exerciseManager =  new ExerciseManager(source, exercisesMarkdown, this.rootUri);
            renderExercise(exerciseManager);
        }.bind(context));
    }

    function renderExercise(exerciseManager) {
        React.render(<ExercisesHeader key="exerciseHeader" exerciseManager={exerciseManager}/>, document.getElementById('mountAppHeader'));
        React.render(<Exercises key="exercises" exerciseManager={exerciseManager}/>, document.getElementById('mountExercisesViewer'));
        React.render(<ExercisesController key="exercisesController" exerciseManager={exerciseManager}/>, document.getElementById('mountExercisesController'));
    }

    renderIndex("https://raw.githack.com/wiki/svdoever/trainercoach/indexhotyoga.md");
```

Strange thing is that this behaviour only occurs on my minified project.

Comment: I noticed that your custom JS is mangled. Are you also using the mangled code when working locally?

Comment: What is strange is that I see request for index.html on the next button, but there is nothing that should be requested! All data is already in...

Comment: @WalterRoman If I run the exact same set of files that I published locally, mangled, minified, it works. I don't see additional web requests. If I host them somewhere else, I see additional web requests on pressing the next button. I'm clueless... For example hosted on dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7197720/www/TrainerCoach/index.html

Comment: on your github version I see three JS errors and the app doesn't even start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521047/warning-react-attempted-to-reuse-markup-in-a-container-but-the-checksum-was-inv)