# Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I'm trying to get an isomorphic Node.js, Express, Webpack, React app working. I'm getting the following error. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) rgin:0;display:flex;-webkit-align-items:
 (server) rgin:0;display:flex;align-items:center;j

warning @   warning.js:45
ReactMount._mountImageIntoNode  @   ReactMount.js:807
wrapper @   ReactPerf.js:66
mountComponentIntoNode  @   ReactMount.js:268
Mixin.perform   @   Transaction.js:136
batchedMountComponentIntoNode   @   ReactMount.js:282
Mixin.perform   @   Transaction.js:136
ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.batchedUpdates @   ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62
batchedUpdates  @   ReactUpdates.js:94
ReactMount._renderNewRootComponent  @   ReactMount.js:476
wrapper @   ReactPerf.js:66
ReactMount._renderSubtreeIntoContainer  @   ReactMount.js:550
ReactMount.render   @   ReactMount.js:570
wrapper @   ReactPerf.js:66
(anonymous function)    @   client.jsx:14
(anonymous function)    @   iso.js:120
each    @   iso.js:21
bootstrap   @   iso.js:111
(anonymous function)    @   client.jsx:12
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap d56606d95d659f2e05dc:19
(anonymous function)    @   bootstrap d56606d95d659f2e05dc:39
(anonymous function)    @   bootstrap d56606d95d659f2e05dc:39
```

This is what is being delivered by the server to the browser initially:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="">

    <head>
        <title>my title</title>

        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="my title" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta name="description" content="my description." data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" data-react-helmet="true" />
<meta charset="utf-8" data-react-helmet="true" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/reset.css" data-react-helmet="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/base.css" data-react-helmet="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/Carousel.css" data-react-helmet="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/styles/main.css" data-react-helmet="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed" type="text/css" data-react-helmet="true" />
<link rel="icon" href="/assets/185bb6f691241307862b331970a6bff1.ico" type="image/x-icon" data-react-helmet="true" />

        SCRIPT

    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/reactfire/0.4.0/reactfire.min.js"></script>

        <div class="app">
<div class="___iso-html___" data-key="_0"><div data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c" data-react-checksum="794698749"><div data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0"><div data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$=10"></div><div style="position:fixed;z-index:2;top:0;left:0;right:0;height:60px;color:rgb(219,219,219);font-family:mainnextcondensed_ultralight;font-size:17px;overflow:hidden;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11"><div style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;background-color:rgba(27,27,27,0.92);padding-right:35px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=10"><div style="float:left;height:60px;width:13px;border-left:5px solid rgb(210,45,164);" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=10.$/=10"></div><div style="float:left;height:60px;width:227px;background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOMAAAAhCAYAAAArrhzzAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAACxNJREFUeNrsXF9sHEcZHx927MZJvU5cSw4FrxXahja451Q88ADeq5Aq0aKeKyh9oMqdyFNA9PzAY3U2vPDE3SGBxNOdaZHKC3c8FCgqvXP73PjqFiSSIl9oSSTXJOe4juv8M/Otv/F9O57ZP+dzaWF+ysjZ3dmd2dn5ze/7vpm5LtYGFr/0otV7wsrdXr1x8dbl6zV+qj7+9nebUZ6xtbXFDAwMWoiFJZ90qjjw7eOp0fJj2XtfeLR6d9Je4nls05wGBu2jO4CENlfABZ7YInsxwU+B+mV77x9Ixg73uHl67xtgR39w0rpWaQAZG6ZJDQw6TEZQw77xo+WRn33Fih3qYQfG7l6Av/2TIwz+euSVHx/+5miOE3aam6s106wGBtHR5UPG4vDzj6QOP/750A9be/mf7Mqv/pa/tbwxG+RDGp/RwCAEGTkRU+AXgin6uV8/yrpHDoZ+4J0Pb7LlH79Z/+idK43Dj486zRfOpzkxK4aMBgYRyciJGOd/qjy5QZtjv/wqu+vUUNsF/PsXf21yQiY4IeuGjAYGIX1GjJoWBRFBEVVE3Di3wtZfv8RunF9loJ79Xzum9CUBR7//kHV7eaPM/cmJqNMfXV1dofJhveN46JlmwcHFfR/jzxp8asjIkSOdWklE8AuXf/Km59z6/GUWy/ewI2e+yAa+c3zXPUM/ethee+U9MH3z+/QeZZ4c/D9EfWtIRAdVPtBHNjD4xJAR/cQUvdgz0u/JfOvy9V1E3PEV126yldwi2zzfZMPPP+K59uGr/wKlquzHC/B6zxAiympZNp+4s+Duhc3/2MIK4dZL09Sxg2REUy5HFXGQq1zQXUr8r8NuXx8bwdIpVC10ySPX/szJBm0w4yijsJqAYXOk/rBNyuBegtV7DB2BtEQ3yawvWMYZYSHzomToGowX+iLA1us7+RwK0iTPsX6vzHs8S/XX7+8c3zo6/daHVSrJHZegYoUhLIU59vFpGh4JA6YKrOYmholzRIigulaArOUJ+goY1ivmuiM2Elr+GEthbln0+8TBUiOKWyTXJuDHsOBSIc0aXsZBTKg0PcS/aESQMbnUCzgOZaswPicDJq5eU0b7AcRGekDRfm7tYOYymcEvPfsa2wlv8i8pus9JGLD/63f8EZNv3eKsYO3SZT1Uss5HTkI0dYsLyujWHge1TylpgGQ4y3JhGBEyfYKYbLFedmuucpJNYOpoTEpBaZkSwCOeYLzQFKqNHNY96SiMwrrhe2BkHUV2UMEQuKoik2f5wtfOI73yH5rXfFewnyf8ylfWCVzqDwNRYwgSdrv40YDCWn5mKvhySjPLVJlA99v80LLTzw4OUIcyBhb+8uSNxp0T7+rmDtZLnh9zMEzJ+yxV5/IwfarPdS5TOoq1EaFqQ6ZxCWigK7Jx9tsCdVZhVHRCTVk1XVoUc5pRWer+AUuQuL3xP/x+FqKlCImP5MGOx3eku6R1dGWfOIwpncW89QI4Ww0vZlUXlT1O616d78gi+a75YlV44QY4LTtHUObPK67efWlVgQVdmjQucf1Py2z1T/8fed4s3GVM7A1lbcpB3zQf+x76IjdpipmiF/rp3z5Tk3wI6HAtMwTUtpIyrjPrc02ie8IdcHOa+3zqK8KJjQ6XEaFDjMK2Nq6LMVic8tpkLcb9uJ6YcAdaxjf7H9fGFde9PfwNEu4l57+aLy/OCZE+7EPpitYukcTmG4W69k3Fi6FinCqJjGqKj2RpJRKSwSUpTUj7x5tntOEd4h4fcu/Foa69RQ+GFTeF1nGlakCGhY5MigUkZVL6DC6NqtqklxKdIrlofBih4XRHETKkXyGWj8TO9MiKCVeE6W1DFBVHwJ63cV+w8QdeJjWqOaD4jDaNu7S+r8RaZZcgQEA/LtBRenXpl98M9PzeAIEZj/7fHfWJL5HPlX6FBZBUFqGsKrTPSmvAcTg0gNaYuWdvuWXI//hS1cqC477/sJXSgeJ/GFT81C8S5FZ1vQZR6aHnd3ZcBCcCCnav+iLxmf+GPpweq30mHJaGDw/wSZjBkWcskUmKVHM+ORfgUAltldOvsGbDKuGzIaGEgBHIU/Ewowoc+JtWvJHAXMT9LdG/KKHAMDA40yRlVHAfo7OUDA7S1UH+wQ0Q3w3GfBTo40RjONmWpgEERGJOQMcIi19t/5AsgmNhOjKborGMK2N+OWiJNtWt/AIIiMEjGTzDtRrQWoI0xtSIsBgIjm1+EMDPZKxr2Yr6y1n0/1swSm9Q0MCGJhM+Lkt26+BsxPmLKASCn9uYNEB3f2GxgYZZRMVlj1ICZ9a2x7eVojasFGGQ0M9kBGQkrwHy3ZDzRkNDBoH/8RYAC6QbxY8FBYtQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=10.$/=11"></div><div style="display:none;width:0;height:0;border-style:solid;border-width:6px 6px 0 6px;border-color:rgb(117,117,117) transparent transparent transparent;-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);float:left;margin-left:6px;margin-top:26px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=10.$/=12"></div></div><div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:280px;width:340px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11"><div style="background-color:rgba(27,27,27,0.92);height:10px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=10"></div><div style="background-color:rgba(53,53,53,0.84);height:40px;position:relative;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=11"><div style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;padding:0;margin:0;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=11.$=10"><div style="background-image:url(&#x27;/assets/3bec3e57cb5ee05658440d21984fb7b7.png&#x27;);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-58px -194px;width:23px;height:22px;position:absolute;top:50%;left:10px;margin-top:-11px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=11.$=10.$icon"></div></div><div style="position:absolute;left:40px;right:40px;top:0px;bottom:0px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=11.$/=12"><input type="text" style="width:100%;height:100%;font-size:14px;font-family:mainnext_regular;background-color:transparent;color:#ffffff;" placeholder="SEARCH ARTISTS, TRACKS, ALBUMS" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=11.$/=12.0"/></div></div><div style="background-color:rgba(27,27,27,0.92);height:10px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=11.$/=12"></div></div><div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:620px;right:0px;background-color:rgba(27,27,27,0.92);height:60px;line-height:60px;overflow:hidden;min-width:500px;padding-left:10px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12"><div style="position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;right:0px;width:357px;padding-left:141px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0"><a class="" href="/import" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$/=10"><div style="padding-left:40px;position:absolute;left:0px;top:10px;bottom:10px;cursor:pointer;line-height:40px;color:rgb(255,255,255);" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$/=10.$import"><div style="position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;padding:0;margin:0;display:flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$/=10.$import.$=10"><div style="background-image:url(&#x27;/assets/3bec3e57cb5ee05658440d21984fb7b7.png&#x27;);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:0px -194px;width:28px;height:28px;position:absolute;top:50%;left:0px;margin-top:-14px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$/=10.$import.$=10.$icon"></div></div><span data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$/=10.$import.1">Import Playlists</span></div></a><div style="margin-left:10px;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$admin/=1$admin"><div style="cursor:pointer;float:left;" data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.0.$/=11.$/=12.0.$admin/=1$admin.$login">Login</div></div></div></div></div></div><noscript data-reactid=".1hkqsbm9n9c.1"></noscript></div></div>
<div class="___iso-state___" data-key="_0" data-meta="{}" data-state="&quot;{\&quot;UserStore\&quot;:{\&quot;user\&quot;:{\&quot;authenticated\&quot;:false,\&quot;isWaiting\&quot;:false}},\&quot;SearchStore\&quot;:{\&quot;focused\&quot;:false,\&quot;input\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;timeout\&quot;:null,\&quot;searchRequests\&quot;:[],\&quot;artists\&quot;:null,\&quot;artistsFailed\&quot;:false,\&quot;artistsLoading\&quot;:false,\&quot;tracks\&quot;:null,\&quot;tracksFailed\&quot;:false,\&quot;tracksLoading\&quot;:false,\&quot;albums\&quot;:null,\&quot;albumsFailed\&quot;:false,\&quot;albumsLoading\&quot;:false,\&quot;playlists\&quot;:null,\&quot;playlistsFailed\&quot;:false,\&quot;playlistsLoading\&quot;:false,\&quot;youtubes\&quot;:null,\&quot;youtubesFailed\&quot;:false,\&quot;youtubesLoading\&quot;:false,\&quot;soundclouds\&quot;:null,\&quot;soundcloudsFailed\&quot;:false,\&quot;soundcloudsLoading\&quot;:false},\&quot;PlayerStore\&quot;:{\&quot;player\&quot;:null,\&quot;playerSecond\&quot;:null,\&quot;playingTrack\&quot;:null,\&quot;playingTrackSecond\&quot;:null,\&quot;videoId\&quot;:null,\&quot;videoIdSecond\&quot;:null,\&quot;makingPlayingTrackPlayable\&quot;:false,\&quot;radio\&quot;:false,\&quot;startSeconds\&quot;:0,\&quot;current\&quot;:0,\&quot;total\&quot;:0,\&quot;perc\&quot;:0,\&quot;currentSecond\&quot;:0,\&quot;totalSecond\&quot;:0,\&quot;percSecond\&quot;:0,\&quot;playing\&quot;:false,\&quot;playingSecond\&quot;:false,\&quot;secondsListened\&quot;:0,\&quot;secondsListenedSecond\&quot;:0,\&quot;expand\&quot;:false,\&quot;source\&quot;:null,\&quot;tracksQueue\&quot;:[],\&quot;tracksPrevQueue\&quot;:[],\&quot;favorite\&quot;:false,\&quot;random\&quot;:false,\&quot;repeat\&quot;:false,\&quot;mute\&quot;:false,\&quot;volume\&quot;:100,\&quot;mode\&quot;:\&quot;standard\&quot;},\&quot;ImportStore\&quot;:{\&quot;url\&quot;:\&quot;\&quot;,\&quot;error\&quot;:false,\&quot;focused\&quot;:false,\&quot;loading\&quot;:false,\&quot;loaded\&quot;:false,\&quot;playlist\&quot;:null}}&quot;"></div>
</div>

        <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
        <!--
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
            ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        -->
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fastclick/1.0.3/fastclick.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          if ('addEventListener' in document) {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                FastClick.attach(document.body);
            }, false);
          }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="/assets/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my server.jsx:

```
import Iso from 'iso';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDomServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { RoutingContext, match } from 'react-router'
import createLocation from 'history/lib/createLocation';

import alt from 'altInstance';
import routes from 'routes.jsx';
import html from 'base.html';

/*
 * @param {AltObject} an instance of the Alt object
 * @param {ReactObject} routes specified in react-router
 * @param {Object} Data to bootstrap our altStores with
 * @param {Object} req passed from Express/Koa server
 */
const renderToMarkup = (alt, state, req, res) => {
  let markup, content;
  let location = new createLocation(req.url);
  alt.bootstrap(state);

  match({ routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (redirectLocation)
      res.redirect(301, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    else if (error)
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    else if (renderProps == null)
      res.status(404).send('Not found')
    else
      content = ReactDomServer.renderToString(<RoutingContext {...renderProps} />);
      markup = Iso.render(content, alt.flush());
  });

  return markup;
};

/* 
 * Export render function to be used in server/config/routes.js
 * We grab the state passed in from the server and the req object from Express/Koa
 * and pass it into the Router.run function.
 */
export default function render(state, req, res) {
  const markup = renderToMarkup(alt, state, req, res);
  return html.replace('CONTENT', markup);
};
```

And this is my client.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Iso from 'iso';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import alt from 'altInstance';
import routes from 'routes.jsx';

/*
 * Client side bootstrap with iso and alt
 */
Iso.bootstrap((state, _, container) => {
  alt.bootstrap(state);
  ReactDOM.render(<Router history={createBrowserHistory()} children={routes} />, container);
});
```

And my routes.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Route from 'react-router';
import App from 'components/App';
import ImportPlaylist from 'components/ImportPlaylist';
import Login from 'components/Login';
import Logout from 'components/Logout';
import Player from 'components/Player/Player';
import Test from 'components/Test';

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route name="test" path="test" component={Test} />        
    <Route name="import" path="import" component={ImportPlaylist} />
    <Route name="player" path="/:playlist" component={Player} />
  </Route>
);
```

Answer (score 107):

**Note:** This applies to older versions of React. **If you're using React 16, you should use [`ReactDOM.hydrate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.htm#hydrate)**

**Also**, the below suggestion will result in a client-side re-render, as suggested by one of the answers below.

---

This may sound crazily simple, but in your server-side template, wrap your React markup in an extra `<div>`:

```
<!-- hypothetical handlebars template -->
<section role="main" class="react-container"><div>{{{reactMarkup}}}</div></section>
```

Why does this work? On the client, React has a propensity to wrap its rendering of your root component with a superfluous div. `ReactDOMServer.render` doesn't seem to behave in this manner, thus when one renders into the same container isomorphically, the Adler-32 checksum of your DOM differs.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the server-side template is in this instance. I've included my client and server side rendering code above in the question, as well as my routes file.

Comment: Aah, you're using the `Iso` module and you're returning static HTML. I'm sorry but I won't be able to help you specifically as I have little experience with this setup, but my answer has worked for me across numerous projects when using an Express template engine and passing my server-side React rendering as a view property.

Comment: Thanks @JamesWright. I'm rendering my root component using `react-dom/renderToString` and inserting it into the document using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }}`, but this solution still worked when I wrapped `content` in an empty div element.

Comment: Thanks I was hitting my head because I was rendering inside a div that contained another content before

Comment: Thanks a lot @JamesWright! Facebook team - is there an issue open for this on github?

Comment: This works but at the same time seems kinda insane.  Shouldn't this be documented/fixed somewhere?

Comment: This is not the solution.

What this is doing is removing the client side shallow render, and instead performing a much slower render, removing the existing DOM entirely, and replacing it with the new result. 

As a consequence it also swallows this error, and any other errors you might have.

Comment: @Alex'Shop'Faunt Will specifying a parent element around the server-side React rendering cause that? Surely this approach would avoid a re-render as there is now parity between the client and server DOM tree. If this is not the case however, could you link to a source to confirm this? I'm still not able to find any other solutions to this issue a year after I posted this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

For those googling and coming here, one weird way of ending up with this issue is where you're not even using isomorphic rendering (i.e. not rendering anything on the server side). This happened with me when using a template with the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to process an `index.html` file.

In my `index.html` file I already included the `bundle.js` file myself, and the above plugin also includes another `bundle.js` via a script-src. Make sure you're setting `inject: false` to your `HtmlWebpackPlugin` constructor.

Comment: Spot on! I'm using Rails, and my bundled js file was being picked up twice. Once when I included it in my page template, and also with `require_tree .` in application.js. I removed the `require_tree .` line in application.js, but that may not be the best solution for everyone.

Answer (score 13):

For me killing nodejs completely and restarting worked

Comment: worked for me as well, but I still wonder what is the root cause and how to prevent this issue

Comment: me too, this sounds weird but IT WORKS

Comment: The issue may be that you don't have hot reloading on the server, but you do on the client. Thus when you make changes, the client code is up to date but the server code isn't, and they produce different results. The restart will ensure client and server are using the same code (until it changes again)

Answer (score 9):

***WARNING*** The popular answer here is not correct. What it is doing is removing the existing DOM entirely, and replacing it with a fresh render on the client. It means you lose the fast shallow render from React and are wasting perf, and as a consequence it also swallows the OP error, and any other errors you might have.

Your issue appears to be with CSS - if you are using autoprefixer and inline-styles that would explain your difference here.

The server side has rendered align-items:center and the client has realised it's in a webkit browser and automatically prefixed it for you to -webkit-align-items.

Please post more info about the CSS set up, and any component using inline-styles or similar.

Comment: Do you have a source with which you can back this up e.g. a file in the React source code? I can't find anything to suggest this, plus I'd expect the markup reuse warning to be emitted even when the initial render is lost. I'm not currently convinced that it's swallowing the error.

Comment: Sorry - I've not logged in in a long time. image: http://imgur.com/a/bbOFr 
code: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/bd2802523c3b1587a79d6ac06cb0e9351b3e68d8/src/renderers/dom/stack/client/ReactMount.js#L563

If you wrap the markup in an additional div you will find that 'shouldReuseMarkup' is false.

Comment: Wow, well you certainly delved deeply! Thanks for pointing this out. I won't remove my answer for posterity's sake but I will certainly specify this information as a warning.

Answer (score 6):

If you are rendering your main content inside of a layout component, you will need to render the layout as static markup (no react attributes) so that the checksum of the content matches between the client and server.

**Server:**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // render the content to a string so it has the same checksum as on the client
  // render the layout to static markup so that it does affect the checksum
  // this ensures that rendering is isomorphic and client doesn't override server markup
  const content = reactDomServer.renderToString(<MyContent />)
  const html = '<!DOCTYPE html>' + reactDomServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<HtmlLayout content={content} />)
  res.send(html)
})
```

**HtmlLayout:**

```
export default class HtmlLayout extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public render () {
    return (
      <html lang='en'>
      <head>
        <meta charSet='utf-8' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/style/bundle.css' />
      </head>
      <body>
        { /* insert the content as a string so that it can be rendered separate with its own checksum for proper server-side rendering */ }
        <div id='content' dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.props.content} } />
        <script src='scripts/bundle.js'></script>
      </body>
      </html>
    )
  }
}
```

**Client:**

```
const root = document.getElementById('content')    
DOM.render(<MyContent />, root)
```

Reference: http://jeffhandley.github.io/QuickReactions/20-final-cleanup

Answer (score 2):

In my case the problem was caused by the fact that I was using MediaQuery component from 'react-responsive' without passing the 'value' property which is used by the component when it is not able to access the screen width (e.g. on the Server).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue on an Isomorphic app I was working on. What worked for me is, believe it or not, Emptying cache and hard reloading the app on Chrome. Looked like the old DOM was somehow cached on the Browser :)

Comment: Did not work for me.  Does anybody actually understand this error?