# reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid (REACT)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

```js
warning.js:36Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) d="22"><div style="-webkit-tap-highlight
 (server) d="22"><div style="-moz-box-sizing:borde
```

Very confused by what this error is saying. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: What about the error is confusing? The message is clear.

Comment: Check out the popular answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521047/warning-react-attempted-to-reuse-markup-in-a-container-but-the-checksum-was-inv

Comment: Greetings. Did you manage to solve this issue? I'm trying to figure it out myself - it seems that the client and server are setting up different styles for the on-tap highlight per different browsers.